# Are specific camera hardware questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

I have a digital camera that is a few years old, and has a specific kind of image quality problems, especially in darker settings.

I'm not a professional photographer, so I'm having a hard time telling whether this is due to some setting I screwed up (or something else I'm doing wrong), or a sign of decay in the camera's hardware.

Would this (including some images to illustrate the problem) be an on-topic question on photography SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd imagine these image problems are probably not limited to *your* camera but probably afflict a number of digital cameras.

So describe the *problem* first and leave the camera model as a footnote.